# Simple Foreingkey in Django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset, many-to-one

I´m begginer in Django.

I've a table in my database called 'produto' and each product belongs a group, I would like show the name that group in same 'for' in that appear the data of product.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Grupo(models.Model):
    codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    tp_linha = models.IntegerField()
    data_alt = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_inc = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'grupo'

class Produto(models.Model):
    codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fabricante = models.IntegerField()
    quantidade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=6)
    preco_venda = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    #...

    grupo_produto = models.ForeignKey(Grupo, related_name='grupo')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'produto'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Servico, Produto, Grupo

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    servicos = Servico.objects.using('mydatabase').all()
    produtos = Produto.objects.using('mydatabase').all()
    grupos = Grupo.objects.using('mydatabase').all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'servicos': servicos, 'produtos': produtos, 'grupos': grupos})
```

home.html

```
{% for Produto in produtos %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{Produto.codigo}}</td>
        <td>{{Produto.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{Produto.referencia}}</td>
        <td>{{Produto.fabricante}}</td>
        <td>{{Produto.quantidade}}</td>
        <td>R$ {{Produto.preco_venda}}</td>
        <td>{{Grupo.nome}}</td>
    </tr>
{% empty %}
    <span>Nenhum resultado encontrado</span>
{% endfor %}
```

I'am lost here, already appear some errors, but I don't know that do.

// UPDATE

I resolved follows way

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Grupo, Produto

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    produtos = Produto.objects.using('horus').raw('SELECT produto.codigo, produto.nome, produto.quantidade, produto.preco_venda, grupo.nome AS nome_grupo FROM produto LEFT JOIN grupo on (produto.grupo = grupo.codigo);');

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'produtos': produtos})

{% for Produto in produtos %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{Produto.codigo}}</td>
            <td>{{Produto.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{Produto.quantidade}}</td>
            <td>R$ {{Produto.preco_venda}}</td>
            <td>{{Produto.nome_grupo}}</td>
        </tr>
{% empty %}
    <span>Nenhum resultado encontrado</span>
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/

I don't know if done right, I would like of tips.

Comment: Also, if you're having errors, please provide a Stack Trace of the errors you receive

Comment: -> I would like show the name that group in same 'for' in that appear the data of product.

What does it mean ?

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Yes, in my database don't have connections among tables, then, I've put SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

try using

`<td>{{Produto.grupo_produto.nome}}</td>`

Does that help?

If that doesn't help try

`<td>{{Produto.grupo.nome}}</td>`

It may just be your related name.

Comment: I tried this, but showed following message: (1054, "Unknown column 'produto.grupo_produto_id' in 'field list'").

Comment: can you put your stack trace and trace back in the post pls?

Comment: Sorry, the fk does not exist in the table structure.

Comment: try `<td>{{Produto.grupo.nome}}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your models, it should be `{{Produto.grupo_produto.nome}}` so if that doesn't work the problem is elsewhere

> (1054, "Unknown column 'produto.grupo_produto_id' in 'field list'")

This suggests that your DB doesn't have that `grupo_produto = ForeignKey(...)` field in it yet, check your DB and the DB migrations, that's where your problem is

P.S.:

No need to try `{{Produto.grupo.nome}}` the `related_name='grupo'` is for accessing the `Produto` objects from a `Grupo` object (products belonging to a group)

Which should have been named `related_name='produtos'` really, that way
you can use `grupo.produtos`, which makes sense

The way you named `related_name='grupo'`, it it would be `grupo.grupo` which doesn't make sense (bad name)